Initialization of static final Fields in Java's System Class in JDK 14 and Beyond
While examining the initialization of the System class in JDK 14 and later, it's evident that the standard input/output streams are set up by invoking the registerNatives() method, which is called from a static initialization block and is itself native. However, what catches the eye is that the variables out, in, and err are defined as static and final. Being final, these fields require explicit initialization with a constant value. Initially, they are set to null within the class.
Considering that their initialization might be handled by a native method, the explicit assignment to null doesn't simply vanish from the code, and logically, this part of the code is expected to execute as well. Furthermore, if we assume that this whole process takes place behind the scenes in the <clinit> method, the native method would complete first, followed by the field initializer that assigns null (for example, looking at the out field). How is null effectively overridden, and where does this actual initialization occur?
Moreover, if we delve into the comments, it becomes apparent that the initialization of this class is somehow separated from the regular execution of <clinit>:
    /* Register the natives via the static initializer.
     *
     * The VM will invoke the initPhase1 method to complete the initialization
     * of this class separate from <clinit>.
     */
    private static native void registerNatives();
    
    static {
        registerNatives();
    }

What is initPhase1? What happens in this phase, and what exactly does it entail? I'm incredibly curious! Thanks to everyone in advance!

I attempted to initialize the standard input/output streams in Java's System class by invoking the registerNatives() method from a static initialization block within JDK 14. Why? It's different on different platforms. Basically everybody but Windows (and mainframes) has "/dev/stdout" and "/dev/stderr" and "/dev/stdin" and they can be used to open file descriptors and begin processing. I used to know how Windows (and mainframes) did it, but the relevance to actual productive work isn't there so I haven't retained it. Best of luck!

@ElliottFrisch Thank you, colleague! I understand that from a practical standpoint, this knowledge might not be very useful to me, but I've always been fascinated by understanding what's happening "under the hood." That's why I asked this question. I wish you good luck and all the best as well!

While examining the initialization of the System class in JDK 14 and later, it's evident that the standard input/output streams are set up by invoking the registerNatives() method, [...]
No, these are not initialized from registerNatives(). They are initialized in the initPhase1() method, which is a regular Java method (in the System class) that is called from native code after the System class has been initialized (i.e. after those fields have been set to null).
The call of initPhase1() is done in a C++ method named initialize_java_lang_classes.

The initialize_java_lang_classes method initializes the System class (among other classes). This initialization executes all static code blocks and all static initalizers.
Later on it executes initPhase1() which is therefore after class initialization.

Assigning to final fields is prohibited for Java code, but native code can still change these fields (see the source for setIn0() on how this is done). The corresponding user-accessible methods (like setIn(), setOut() and setErr()) exist since Java 1.1. I can only assume that in Java 1.0 you could not change System.in and System.out.

What does registerNatives() do?
If you look at the source for registerNatives() it registers some of the native methods of the System class with the JVM. From the comment just above that method it does this for performance reasons.
I've linked the registerNatives() method in the block before, I include it here for completeness. Clearly it doesn't do anything like calling initPhase1():

/* Only register the performance-critical methods */
static JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
    {"currentTimeMillis", "()J",              (void *)&JVM_CurrentTimeMillis},
    {"nanoTime",          "()J",              (void *)&JVM_NanoTime},
    {"arraycopy",     "(" OBJ "I" OBJ "II)V", (void *)&JVM_ArrayCopy},
};

#undef OBJ

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_java_lang_System_registerNatives(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls)
{
    (*env)->RegisterNatives(env, cls,
                            methods, sizeof(methods)/sizeof(methods[0]));
}



The code block from the System.java source:

    /* Register the natives via the static initializer.
     *
     * The VM will invoke the initPhase1 method to complete the initialization
     * of this class separate from <clinit>.
     */
    private static native void registerNatives();
    static {
        registerNatives();
    }


seems to fool you: you are thinking that initPhase1 is somehow called from registerNatives(). But as the source code for registerNatives() shows this is not the case.
And also: registerNatives() is called from a static initializer block which means it is called from <clinit>. If registerNatives() really did call initPhase1() that would mean it would be called indirectly from <clinit> which contradicts the comment: The VM will invoke the initPhase1 method [...] separate from <clinit>

As for the code of the native setIn0() method (also already linked above), this is also found in System.c:

/*
 * The following three functions implement setter methods for
 * java.lang.System.{in, out, err}. They are natively implemented
 * because they violate the semantics of the language (i.e. set final
 * variable).
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_java_lang_System_setIn0(JNIEnv *env, jclass cla, jobject stream)
{
    jfieldID fid =
        (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env,cla,"in","Ljava/io/InputStream;");
    if (fid == 0)
        return;
    (*env)->SetStaticObjectField(env,cla,fid,stream);
}


(I did not bother to copy the code for setOut0 and setErr0 since their code is the same except for the names of the fields.)
Note that comment above the native functions: it clearly states their purpose and that these functions do something the Java language does not allow.

Thank you so much for your response! If you allow me, I would like to clarify some details. If the initialization to null happens first, how can it be overridden, considering the fact that this is prohibited for final variables? Even if initPhase1 is called from a native method, shouldn't it execute before the assignment to null? If we examine the sequence of instructions, that’s exactly how it should happen. And ultimately, what does the registerNatives() method initialize in this case?

If we examine the sequence of instructions, that’s exactly how it should happen. Why do you think so? Generally classes are loaded and initialized and only then can you call methods on them.

Yes, you're correct. I'll try to explain my point more clearly and succinctly. In my understanding, the initialization of the class is handled by the  method, which can be observed at the level of Java bytecode. This includes all static initialization blocks and field initializers. In our case, there is the registerNatives() method within such a block, followed by expressions that explicitly initialize fields (as with the direct assignment of null).

It appears that the registerNatives() method is executed first, within which the initPhase1() is called, as you rightly mentioned. Thus, in my understanding, the aforementioned methods should execute first, and then, judging from the existing listing, the initialization of the fields using explicitly specified null value should occur. In other words, my reasoning is based on the existing source code.

I just don't fully understand one thing. Why exactly is initPhase1 positioned after the class initialization, as you indicated in your detailed response, if it is called directly from the registerNatives() method, as I understood? Or do native methods operate in a special way and are executed separately after all the Java methods in the class initialization block are completed? If that's the case, I honestly didn't know about it. This particular point is still causing some confusion in my mind.

I don't understand why you think initPhase1() is called directly from the registerNatives() method when the source code of registerNatives() clearly shows that it does not call initPhase1.

Thank you for the detailed breakdown! I've reviewed everything and now I fully understand the invocation sequence. I should have been more observant. It turns out that  is actually invoked as a distinct method from the native function Threads::initialize_java_lang_classes(JavaThread* main_thread, TRAPS), followed separately by the call to initPhase1() from within the same method!
This clarification really helps in understanding the initialization process in Java. Thanks again for your thorough explanation!

Finally, to wrap up the topic, I'd like to understand how native setters work. Do they not require reflection or similar mechanisms to modify final fields? If the code is written in C/C++, can we directly access a specific memory cell and change its value at runtime as if nothing happened using a native method like this? Are there no restrictive checks performed? I've never really considered these properties of native code before.

Thank you for everything! This was one of the most detailed responses one could imagine! I am very grateful!

“Assigning to final fields is prohibited for Java code” is a misleading statement, at best. There are three different scenarios: 1) Assigning to ordinary final instance fields (outside the constructor) is possible via Reflection with access override. 2) Assigning static final fields or final fields of records or hidden classes after their initialization, is not supported in general. 3) The three fields System.out, System.err, and System.in are so special that the specification provides them their own category

while the explicit assignment to null in the code may seem redundant, it serves as a placeholder value until the actual initialization occurs through native methods. The initialization process ensures that the standard input/output streams are properly set up before they are accessed by the Java application

Yes, I completely agree with you. This is necessary so that the compiler will even allow such code, as we are required to explicitly initialize all final fields that we have in our code. I was simply curious about where exactly the initialization of the standard streams occurs and how the null collision is resolved. Overall, I was already given a bit of guidance on how it happens. Now it's becoming a bit clearer. In any case, thank you so much for not just passing by!
